# Extending Main Partition With Existing Free Space

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I want to extend my main /dev/sdb7 disk by using unallocated 146.49 GiB free space.

However i cant see any free space when i try to resize it.

The main partition contents should be conserved and extended.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can't operate on mounted partitions (indicated by the key icon).

Comment: But there should be a way to extend your main partition according to your increased needs

Comment: You have to boot into a live environment and do it while the partition is unmounted.

Comment: okey i have live disks. i will try resize options on it but i need to keep the files on my root /. it will keep it and just resize it right?

Comment: I always suggest having solid, tested backups before performing any partition operations. Any mistake can result in loss of data. But that said, it should be ok to do what you want.

Comment: it has worked! thank you man. when i opened gparted it was locked like before, after unmount / partition it was unlocked, then resized it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!